# Document never becomes ready to get information from database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Basically the problems that I am having is that I have a section of script that is set to execute when the select box "graded" changes. Basically what happens in the document never becomes ready. When I use Chrome's console to print out the studentid and graderid values they are empty. I put an "exit();" function in the displayeval.php page and was able to find out that the document never becomes ready.

I realize a lot of this code is messed up and very novice, but I am working like a crazy man to finish up this project before the end of the week for class and I just want it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#graded').change(function () {
        var studentid = $('#studentid').val();
        var graderid = $(this).val();
        $.get("displayeval.php?graderid=" + graderid + "&studentid=" + studentid, function (data) {
            $('#behavior-290').val(data.comment);
        }, "json");
    });
});
```

instructoreval.php

```
    <?php
include('includes/header.php');
$student_id=$_GET['studentid'];
if($session->userlevel>=8)

//if they are an instructor
{
 if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
      $query="SELECT * FROM Behavior b, Groups g WHERE g.GROUP_ID=" . $session->GROUP_ID . " AND b.CONTRACT_ID=g.CONTRACT_ID";
      $btwo = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
      $numB = mysql_num_rows($btwo);
      $query2="INSERT INTO Eval (STUDENT_ID, Grader_ID, GROUP_ID, Grade) VALUES (" . $_POST[graded] . ", " . $session->STUDENT_ID . ", " . $session->GROUP_ID . ", '10')";
      mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

      $evalid = mysql_insert_id();
      for($i=0;$i<$numB;$i++){ 
        $r2 = mysql_fetch_array($btwo);
        $query3="INSERT INTO EvalComment (CONTRACT_ID, BEHAVIOR_ID, Comment, EVAL_ID) VALUES (" . $r2[CONTRACT_ID] . ", " . $r2[BEHAVIOR_ID] . ", \"" . $_POST[$r2[BEHAVIOR_ID]] . "\", " . $evalid . ")";
        mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
      };
      $qfour = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE GROUP_ID=" . $session->GROUP_ID . " AND STUDENT_ID=" . $_POST[graded]);
      $rfour = mysql_fetch_array($qfour);
      popup("Your comments for " . $rfour[lname] . ", " . $rfour[fname] . " have been submitted.");
    };


            $link = mysql_connect("localhost","drallen1","unicode") or die(mysql_error);
            mysql_select_db("drallen1");

            $qsix = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.GROUP_ID=" . $session->GROUP_ID . " AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Eval e WHERE u.STUDENT_ID=e.STUDENT_ID) AND u.STUDENT_ID!=" . $session->STUDENT_ID);
            $numE = mysql_num_rows($qsix);
            /***************************************************
            //WHEN numE == 0 GO TO PIE CHART
            ***************************************************/
            //QUERY
            $qtwo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Behavior b, Groups g WHERE g.GROUP_ID=" . $session->GROUP_ID . " AND b.CONTRACT_ID=g.CONTRACT_ID");
             // match eval id
            $numB = mysql_num_rows($qtwo);

            if($numE>1)
              $page="evalform.php";
            else
              $page="evalprocess.php";

              echo "<form action=$page method=\"POST\">";?>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#graded').change(
                                function() {
                                var studentid = $('#studentid').val();
                                var graderid = $(this).val();

                                $.get( "displayeval.php?graderid=" + graderid + "&studentid=" + studentid,
                                   function(data){
                                        $('#behavior-290').val(data.comment);
                                   }, "json");
                            });
                    });
        </script>
            <input type="hidden" name="studentid" id="studentid" value="<?php echo $_GET['studentid'];?>" />
            Student: <select name="graded" id="graded">
              <option selected="selected">Please Select a Student to Grade</option>
              <?php for($i=0;$i<$numE;$i++){
                $rsix = mysql_fetch_array($qsix);?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rsix[STUDENT_ID]?>"><?php echo $rsix[fname] . " " . $rsix[lname]?></option>
              <?php };?>
            </select></br></br>

            <!--$qthree = mysql_query("SELECT EVAL_ID FROM Eval WHERE GRADER_ID=" . $student_id. " AND STUDENT_ID=" . graded.value ); -->

            <?php for($i=0;$i<$numB;$i++){ 
            //result of qtwo
              $rtwo = mysql_fetch_array($qtwo);
              echo "Behavior: <input name=\"BEHAVIOR_ID\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $rtwo[BehaviorName] . "\" readonly=\"readonly\"/> </br>";

                //$queryshit="SELECT Comment FROM EvalComment WHERE EVAL_ID=RESULTFROMQTHREE AND BEHAVIOR_ID=" . $rtwo[BEHAVIOR_ID];
                //$comments;

              echo "Comments: <textarea name=\"" . $rtwo['BEHAVIOR_ID'] . "\" id=\"behavior-" . $rtwo['BEHAVIOR_ID'] . "\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"50\">". $comments . "</textarea> </br>"; ?>
            <?php };?>
            </br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send!" name="Submit"/>
          </form>
        </body>

   </html>

    <? include("includes/footer.php"); 
  }else{
  echo "You don't have access to this.";
};?>
```

displayeval.php

```
    <?php
include('include/session.php');


$grader_id=$_GET['graderid'];
$student_id=$_GET['studentid'];

$query="SELECT EVAL_ID FROM Eval WHERE GRADER_ID=". $grader_id . " AND STUDENT_ID=" . $student_id;

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$eval_id=$data['EVAL_ID'];

$query="SELECT BEHAVIOR_ID,Comment comment FROM EvalComment WHERE EVAL_ID=". $eval_id;
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$data2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
//print_r($data2);


// query database based on GET params

// fetch result
// $mysql_row = mysql_fetch_assoc()

// display in JSON: 
echo json_encode( $data2 );
```

this is the result of the displayeval(displayeval.php?graderid=0&studentid=241654664) page

```
{"BEHAVIOR_ID":"1","comment":"Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write Write"}
```

Comment: What browser are you testing on?  Put a breakpoint at 'var studentid' and see if it is getting called too early.

Comment: What do you mean "the document never becomes ready" - do you mean the client-side javascript never executes, or the server-side code doesn't finishing running, or ? If the problem is in the front-end Javascript code, the PHP you've posted is irrelevant, and vice versa.

Comment: can you show the html output?

Comment: I was able to get the script to work once with test data. Once I changed the displayeval page to actually do a mysql query is when I started having issues. The weird thing is if I put an alert in the document ready function and comment the rest of the script out, it never executes, therefore the document never becomes "ready." Jquery is included in the header file and working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the `$('#graded')` element exists, try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#graded').attr('id'));   // should alert 'graded'
});
```

Second, if you are loading it dynamically (after the page has been rendered) you will need to declare the `change()` method via a `$.bind()` or `$.live()` event.

```
$('#graded').live('change', function () {
    ...
});
```

Finally, be careful with `$.change()`.

For checkboxes, you may want to do this:

```
$('#graded').change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // the checkbox is now checked, do something
    } else {
        // the checkbox is now UN-checked, do something else
    }
});
```

In addition to all that (KISS principle), make sure the jQuery library is in fact being loaded:

```
if (jQuery) { 
   alert('jQuery is loaded');
}
```

Comment: I tried using the $('#graded').live('change', function () {
    ...
}); but that didn't work. I used the alert, which did work. I put the alert inside the change function, which also alerted when I changed the select box. It must have something to do with the url that I am GETing

Comment: I'm all set thanks, ended up getting it to work. Problem was with the variables